# Attempting to passthru USB disk to XENserver windows guest, reporting wrong size and error

Tags: partitioning, virtualization, usb-storage, xenserver

I am attempting to passthru a brand new Seagate USB disk (4TB) to a Windows 2008 virtual guest in XEN 6.2.  I connected the device, it is listed properly by fdisk -l (even lists correct size, but says Use GPT due to size).  I used gdisk to create GPT partition table and partion 1 as EFI GPT type (700).  The disk is then listed in XenCenter under Removable Storage, and displays the correct size there.

Then I used XenCenter to "attach" the disk to my virutual guest Windows 2008 x64 server.  The disk immediately appears in Computer Management: Storage as an uninitialized disk, but the size is reported as 29,808GB (30TB??? WOW!) and any attempt to initialize, offline, etc, yields error message "The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error."

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Is it possibly the wrong partition type?  I got the same results before doing any fiddling with the partitions (i.e. new out of box).  Then I used gdisk to set GPT partition type and create a single partition, still got same error and incorrect size reporting from Windows guest.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: To me this looks like a 512- vs 4096-byte sector size issue, especially due to the reported size being approx 30TB vs 3.5TB ( roughly 8 times, same as 512 vs 4096 byte sectors) but i dont know how to fix. Windows 2008 x64 is supposed to support 4096 byte sectors... Right?

Comment: Is it impossible to passthru the device? Should i instead create a local storage repository for this drive? It was intended for backups...

Comment: Looks like 4096-byte sectors may be the culprit... http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/306773-xenserver-56-and-problem-with-attached-4k-sector-usb-drive/

Comment: But what i don't understand is that the host sees and correctly reports the drive and its capacity, just fails to pass thru to guest.  Is this a bug with the usb passthru system?

Comment: Ok so I'm adding the drive as local storage instead, using this reference http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/6.2.0/1.0/en_gb/reference.html?&_ga=1.176539810.602237306.1420439986#id475618

Comment: That failed also.  I was able to add the SR, but then creating virtual disks on the SR yields errors and fails.